# Searchview identifying only Uppercase letter. But I want both upper and lower case letter results

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchMenu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


                ArrayList<Music> results= new ArrayList<>();

                for (Music x:arrayList)
                {
                    if (x.getSinger().contains(newText))
                        results.add(x);


                }
                ((CustomMusicAdapter)songList.getAdapter()).update(results);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

In listview I put searchview. Searchview is working on toolbar, but it is only identify and giving results upper case letters . Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use the equalsIgnoreCase method of the String class.

modify like below if condition.

```
      for (Music x:arrayList)
            {
                  if (x.getSinger().equalsIgnoreCase(newText))
                      results.add(x);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It's not working in a good proper way

Comment: I want my application searching like that : https://youtu.be/SAiK6-CgVv8

Comment: Can you please write your mail, I would explain my question clearly

Comment: Have you tried this one?                                                                                               if (x.getSinger().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase()))
                      results.add(x);

Comment: Ah! That's all! Sorry it was my fault , bro :)

Comment: it's okay bro :)